# Binding binary data to ComponentOne WebReport control

Tags: componentone

Any idea how one can bind binary data to a ComponentOne WebReport control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ComponentOne has a new C1ReportViewer control and WebReport is now legacy, but they both support the same report formats. Below is an example of a report defenition with bound images. You can see the live version of it here: [ASP.NET Report Demo](http://demo.componentone.com/aspnet/controlexplorer/C1ReportViewer/C1Reports.aspx). You will want to choose report #4 to see it. Feel free to download the latest version of Studio for ASP.NET AJAX to download the source code too.

```
 <Report version="2.5.20061.196">
<Name>04: Bound Images</Name>
<ReportInfo />
<DataSource>
  <ConnectionString>Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DATADIRECTORY|\c1nwind.mdb;Persist Security Info=False</ConnectionString>
  <RecordSource>Employees</RecordSource>
</DataSource>
<Layout>
  <PageHeader>1</PageHeader>
</Layout>
<Font>
  <Name>Verdana</Name>
  <Size>9</Size>
</Font>
<Groups />
<Sections>
  <Section>
    <Name>Detail</Name>
    <Type>0</Type>
    <Height>2915</Height>
  </Section>
  <Section>
    <Name>Header</Name>
    <Type>1</Type>
    <Height>1835</Height>
    <BackColor>11829830</BackColor>
  </Section>
  <Section>
    <Name>Footer</Name>
    <Type>2</Type>
    <Visible>0</Visible>
  </Section>
  <Section>
    <Name>PageHeader</Name>
    <Type>3</Type>
    <Height>915</Height>
  </Section>
  <Section>
    <Name>PageFooter</Name>
    <Type>4</Type>
    <Height>500</Height>
  </Section>
</Sections>
<Fields>
  <Field>
    <Name>titleLbl</Name>
    <Section>1</Section>
    <Text>Bound Images</Text>
    <Top>200</Top>
    <Width>9360</Width>
    <Height>600</Height>
    <Align>6</Align>
    <ForeColor>16777215</ForeColor>
    <Font>
      <Bold>-1</Bold>
      <Name>Verdana</Name>
      <Size>18</Size>
    </Font>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>ftrLeft</Name>
    <Section>4</Section>
    <Text>Now()</Text>
    <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
    <Top>180</Top>
    <Width>4680</Width>
    <Height>300</Height>
    <Align>0</Align>
    <Font>
      <Name>Verdana</Name>
      <Size>8.25</Size>
    </Font>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>ftrRight</Name>
    <Section>4</Section>
    <Text>"Page " &amp; [Page] &amp; " of " &amp; [Pages]</Text>
    <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
    <Left>4680</Left>
    <Top>180</Top>
    <Width>4680</Width>
    <Height>300</Height>
    <Align>2</Align>
    <Font>
      <Name>Verdana</Name>
      <Size>8.25</Size>
    </Font>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>LastNameCtl</Name>
    <Section>0</Section>
    <Text>FirstName &amp; " " &amp; LastName</Text>
    <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
    <Left>2340</Left>
    <Top>180</Top>
    <Width>6300</Width>
    <Height>300</Height>
    <Align>0</Align>
    <Font>
      <Bold>-1</Bold>
      <Name>Verdana</Name>
      <Size>11.25</Size>
    </Font>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>AddressCtl</Name>
    <Section>0</Section>
    <Text>Address &amp; vbcrlf &amp; City &amp; vbcrlf &amp; Country</Text>
    <Calculated>-1</Calculated>
    <Left>2340</Left>
    <Top>720</Top>
    <Width>6300</Width>
    <Height>1800</Height>
    <Align>0</Align>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>Field1</Name>
    <Section>0</Section>
    <Left>180</Left>
    <Top>180</Top>
    <Width>1980</Width>
    <Height>2340</Height>
    <Picture>Photo</Picture>
    <PictureScale>2</PictureScale>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>Field</Name>
    <Section>1</Section>
    <Text>This report has a field bound to images stored in the database. The field's Picture property is set to the string "Photo", which is the name of a binary field that contains employee photos stored as embedded OLE bitmaps. Images stores as raw byte streams would also work.</Text>
    <Top>990</Top>
    <Width>9270</Width>
    <Height>810</Height>
    <ForeColor>16777215</ForeColor>
    <MarginLeft>200</MarginLeft>
    <CanGrow>-1</CanGrow>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>LastNameLbl</Name>
    <Section>3</Section>
    <Text>NorthWind International</Text>
    <Left>975</Left>
    <Top>30</Top>
    <Width>2610</Width>
    <Height>300</Height>
    <Align>3</Align>
    <ForeColor>11829830</ForeColor>
    <WordWrap>0</WordWrap>
    <Font>
      <Bold>-1</Bold>
      <Name>Verdana</Name>
      <Size>9</Size>
    </Font>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>divLine</Name>
    <Section>3</Section>
    <Top>390</Top>
    <Width>9360</Width>
    <Height>60</Height>
    <BackColor>0</BackColor>
    <BackStyle>1</BackStyle>
    <PictureScale>2</PictureScale>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>LastNameLbl1</Name>
    <Section>3</Section>
    <Text>Employee List</Text>
    <Left>975</Left>
    <Top>465</Top>
    <Width>2610</Width>
    <Height>375</Height>
    <Align>0</Align>
    <ForeColor>11829830</ForeColor>
    <WordWrap>0</WordWrap>
    <Font>
      <Bold>-1</Bold>
      <Name>Verdana</Name>
      <Size>9</Size>
    </Font>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>Field2</Name>
    <Section>3</Section>
    <Top>30</Top>
    <Width>900</Width>
    <Height>810</Height>
    <ZOrder>1</ZOrder>
    <Picture encoding="base64">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</Picture>
    <PictureScale>2</PictureScale>
  </Field>
  <Field>
    <Name>Field3</Name>
    <Section>4</Section>
    <Top>150</Top>
    <Width>9345</Width>
    <Height>30</Height>
    <BorderStyle>1</BorderStyle>
    <LineSlant>1</LineSlant>
  </Field>
</Fields>
```